# Repeated column in mapping for entity with hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am using hibernate to do a project. And I have a problem with my mapping.
I got this error :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: org.el_dao.entity.Save column: idModel (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Here is the entity :

```
@Embeddable
public class SaveId implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "login", referencedColumnName = "login")
    private User login;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "idStep", referencedColumnName = "idStep", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "idModel3", referencedColumnName = "idModel", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "idPart2", referencedColumnName = "idPart", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "idPiece", referencedColumnName = "idPiece", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private Step idStep;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "idPart", referencedColumnName = "idPart", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "idModel", referencedColumnName = "idModel", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private Part idPart;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idModel", referencedColumnName = "idModel", insertable=false,  updatable=false)
    private Model idModel;
```

And the entity that uses the previous one :

```
@Entity
@Proxy(lazy = false)
@Table(name = "save", schema = "public")
public class Save implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Save's id
     */
    @EmbeddedId
    private SaveId saveId;
```

I have already used several choices without result like adding insert and update in false.

Answer (score 0):

According to the hibernate documentation:

> Each of the persistent properties or fields of the embedded object is
>   mapped to the database table for the entity.

So in your case the entity Save  will have two column named idModel that why hibernate is complaining. You should change the name of one of the Join Columns, for example:

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "idModel2", referencedColumnName = "idModel", insertable=false,  updatable=false)
    private Model idModel;
```

Comment: You should add the annotation @Columns to private SaveId saveId whith the respectives colums;